# splitting tfrecords dataset with multiple features

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have an image classification task where I've created multiple crops of each image as well as flipped/flopped versions to extend my limited dataset. I have written the dataset to a tfrecords file where each record consists of (simplified here to two crops and only a flipped version):

```
    {
        lbl: int, 
        crop_0: np.ndarray, 
        crop_1: np.ndarray,
        crop_0_flipped: np.ndarray, 
        crop_1_flipped: np.ndarray
    }
```

Basically 4 images / entry. During training, I'd like to treat each image as separate, i.e. feed each record as 4 images with the same label, shuffled with the rest of the images in the dataset, so that *N* images becomes *4N* images. During testing (using a separate but similarly structured dataset), I'd like to take each image, only use the crop_0 and crop_1 images and average the softmax outputs for classification.

My question is - what is the best and most efficient way of training such a dataset? I'm willing to change my approach if this will make training more inefficient, and it seems that the simplest thing to do would have been to have separate tfrecords files for each version (crop & flip/flop images) and interleave the files into one dataset, but I do not want to have a whole bunch of files to deal with if I can help it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the dataset to disk with 4N images is an approach that you'll come to loath later (I did it this way originally and loath that code now). The better way is to keep your original dataset on disk as-is, don't write your preprocessing steps to disk. Do that kind of preprocessing in the CPU while you train. The tensorflow Dataset preprocessing pipeline makes this easy, modular, and provides the parallelization you need to take advantage of multiple cores at not extra coding expense.

This is the main guide:

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets

Your approach should be to create 2 Dataset objects, one for train and one for test. The train Dataset pipeline will perform all the data augmentation you mentioned. The test Dataset pipeline will not, naturally.

One key to understanding this approach is that you will not feed the data to tensorflow using `feed_dict`, instead, tensorflow will just invoke the Dataset pipeline to pull the data it needs for each batch.

To get parallelization you'll use the `Dataset.map` function to apply some set of transformations and use the property `num_parallel_calls` to distribute the operations across multiple cores. If your preprocessing can be done in tensorflow code, great, if not you'll need to use `tf.py_func` to use python preprocessing code.

The guide I linked to above describes all of this very well. You will want to us a feedable iterator described in the section called "Creating an iterator". This will allow you to get a string ID from each of the 2 datasets (train and test) and pass that string to tensorflow via `feed_dict` indicating which of the two datasets tensorflow should pull samples from.